# meaning of "about us" in "about us for that"

Tags: relative-pronouns, idioms

> We will need our full wits and strength about us for that

This is the first time I saw "about us" which was put in a strange place in the sentence like this. And Is there any grammar structure of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usage *have your wits about you* is effectively an idiomatic "fixed phrase", where to have something *about you* means ***with you, close to hand, ready for use***. Come to that, this usage of ***wits*** (meaning ***intelligence, common sense, understanding***) is becoming quite rare itself now.

You'd rarely encounter it used of anything other than ***wits***. OP's cited example is bordering on "playing" with language by including ***strength*** - which is "licensed" by the fact that ***wits*** is also mentioned (no-one would be likely to use the "bare" *You need to have your strength about you*).